# OpenCV Image Display Failure

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to include OpenCV (version 2.3.1) in a project I'm working on. A camera is sending my program (in Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 on a Windows 7 64-bit machine) an image stream, which the program stores in an unsigned 8-bit integer buffer. I would like to display this stream in a window using OpenCV. Right now, I can't seem to get any images to display in my OpenCV windows, so I'm not using my image stream yet; just a JPEG file.

First I declare my window:

```
namedWindow( "Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
```

Then I try to fill it:

```
char* imgName = "C:\...\Jellyfish.jpg";
Mat imgMat = imread(imgName, 1);
if(imgMat.data)
{
     imshow( "Window", imgMat );
}
```

When my program gets to the point where the window gets declared, a tiny gray window appears. When it reaches the point where it is supposed to display the image, the window's dimensions change to that of the image (I've tested this with different images) but the inside of the window remains a plain gray box.

What is causing this strange error? The program obviously found the image, or it would not have been able to change its dimensions correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `waitKey(2)` function call after the `imshow`.

From OpenCV documentation for waitKey:

> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle
>   events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event
>   processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes
>   care of event processing.

Without this function Windows is unable to handle PAINT event and redraw your window.

Comment: Thanks, I added that function and the image is now displayed in the window. I need to read the documentation for it, I was worried it would affect the speed of my video stream but it hasn't made a noticeable difference.